# cannot call value from other table with eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
 @foreach($sudah as $sudah)
                    <tr>
                        <td class=" font-size-sm">{{$sudah->nama}}</td>
                        <td class="text-center font-size-sm">{{$sudah->nik}}</td>
                        <td class="text-center font-size-sm">{{$sudah->nkk}}</td>

                        <td class="text-center font-size-sm">
                            <em >{{ date('d-M-Y H:i:s', strtotime($sudah->created_at))}}</em>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center d-none d-sm-table-cell">
                            <span class="badge badge-success">{{$sudah->validasi_pbu->user->name}}</span>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center font-size-sm">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Detail">
                                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-list-alt"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit">
                                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-edit"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete">
                                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash-alt"></i>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
```

```
public function index(){

   $belum = DB::table('datapemilihbaru')->where('validasi','0')->get();
   $sudah= datapemilihbaru::where('validasi','1')->get();
   return view('/pages/admin/validasi',compact('sudah','belum'));

}
```

```
class datapemilihbaru extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'datapemilihbaru';
    protected $fillable = ['email','nama_lembaga','KEC','Desa_Kel','nkk', 'nik','nama','tempat_lahir','tanggal_lahir','kawin','jenis_kelamin','alamat','rt','rw','difabel','status_ktp','keterangan','foto_ktp','foto_ktpfp','foto_kk','foto_kkfp','validasi'];


    public function User(){
        return $this->belongToMany('App\User','validasi_pbu','datapemilihbaru_id','users_id')->withTimeStamps();
    }
}
```

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\datapemilihbaru;
use App\User;

class validasi_pbu extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'validasi_pbu';
    protected $fillable = ['users_id','datapemilihbaru_id'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

}
```

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\datapemilihbaru;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

   public function datapemilihbaru(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\datapemilihbaru','validasi_pbu','users_id','datapemilihbaru_id')->withTimeStamps();
    }

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

This is the result when i try to call the **name from user**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTbVq.png)

but, when i try call the validasi_pbu value, the result just null value, even though the validation_pbu table contains contents

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPQOa.png)

this is the result (under column **divalidasi oleh**)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWIBm.png)

Please somebody help me :(
i am a newbie

Comment: In your model, it's `belongstoMany` and not `belongtoMany`.

Comment: still can't run, after i fixed the typo

Comment: `@foreach($sudah as $sudah)` may be incorrect format

Comment: i use that format i have no problem with my foreach, that's can running as a normal